# Why can we create two zone with identical ones DNS name?

Tags: dns, google-cloud-dns

In google cloud dns, we can create two zones with different names but the same dns names. Why is this necessary? How can dns names be the same?
In what cases may this be necessary?
[image: example in google cloud dns]

Answer (score 1):

A DNS zone can contain multiple subdomains of a particular domain (which you can create by adding record sets in your zone). In many circumstances, there's uneven traffic on different subdomains of a domain. Some high traffic prone subdomains of a domain are hosted in different zones than other subdomains, in order to provide separate management overhead to them. This way, multiple zones have to be created even when their domain names are the same.
For further reading on DNS zones, refer to [this](https://www.cloudflare.com/en-in/learning/dns/glossary/dns-zone/).

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know this topic very well. If you create the same resourserecordset records in the same managed zone, then where will the traffic go?

Comment: Just to clarify, ‘zones’ are created for segregated management overhead; traffic will go as per the DNS server policies you create for your respective ‘zones’.  
Check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OH_Jw8NhEGU) for a more clear understanding of cloud DNS.